# Pass a function as an argument in an ng-template Angular

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have 4 buttons where I want them to do different actions but they all look the same with different images. So I've created an ng-template to render them. My idea was to pass the function that each one was going to call as a parameter in the ng-template but I can't find a way to do it.

Here is my idea:

```ts
<ng-template #tempalte let-icon=icon let-action=action let-alt=alt>
  <div (click)="action()">
    <img src={{icon}} alt={{alt}}>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Or it's my logic wrong and I am making a mistake?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can totally do that with providing a context.

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tempalte;context:ctx"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tempalte;context:ctx2"></ng-container>


<ng-template #tempalte let-icon="icon" let-action="action" let-alt="alt">
  <div (click)="action()">
    <img src={{icon}} alt={{alt}}>
    Button
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
  ctx = { action: () => alert('button1') };
  ctx2 = { action: () => alert('button2') };
```

Here's the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmsjm7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)